# Calling group function on non EAV model

Tags: magento

I need to use group in my collection. Here's how I am doing it:

```
$products = Mage::getModel("similar/blogpost")->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('designid',''.$pid)->group('categoryname');
```

My Collection class is like this:

```
<?php
class Homeliv_Similar_Model_Resource_Blogpost_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract {
    protected function _construct()
    {
            $this->_init('similar/blogpost');
    }
} ?>
```

I am getting fatal error: undefined method

Answer (score 0):

try with below..

```
$products = Mage::getModel("similar/blogpost")->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('designid',$pid);
$products->getSelect()->group('categoryname');
```

Answer (score 0):

please remove `''` before $pid

```
 $products = Mage::getModel("similar/blogpost")->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('designid', $pid)->group('categoryname');
```